# Comparator from nested POJO

Tags: java, java-8, comparator, comparable

I want to sort a list of my POJO by a property that is also a POJO. The Comparator should move `null` values to the end of the list. The `null`s are already at second POJO level.

Assume following POJOs:

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;
    private boolean set;
    // getter and setter omitted
}

public class Bar {
    private String name1;
    private String name2;
    // getter and setter omitted
}
```

Now I have a `List<Foo>` which should be sorted by `Bar#name1`.

So far I have following code:

```
Collections.sort(fullList, Comparator.comparing(Foo::getBar::getName1,
        Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

This sadly doesn't work, as the `::` operator can't be chained. So I updated `Bar` class to implement `Comparator<Bar>`

```
public class Bar implements Comparator<Bar> {
    private String name1;
    private String name2;
    // getter and setter omitted

    @Override
    public int compare(Bar o1, Bar o2) {
        return o1.getName1().compareTo(o2.getName1());
    }
}
```

and changed my sorting code to:

```
Collections.sort(fullList, Comparator.comparing(Foo::getBar,
        Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

But this gives me compilation errors:

> The method comparing(Function, Comparator) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments (Foo::getBar, Comparator>>)

as well as

> The type Foo does not define getBar(T) that is applicable here

**What am I doing wrong on my second part? How do I fix it?**

---

**EDIT:**

I just realized that a crucial part is missing.

In the list, `Foo`s are never `null`, but `Bar` might be `null`. In the case that `Bar` is `null`, the `Foo` should be moved to the end of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simply use the lambda with your first approach:

```
fooList.sort(Comparator.comparing(f -> f.getBar().getName1(),
            Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
```

---

While you are looking towards making `Bar` comparable, you should do:

```
@Getter
class Bar implements Comparable<Bar> {
    private String name1;
    private String name2;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Bar o) {
        return name1.compareTo(o.getName1());
    }
}
```

and follow it up with

```
fooList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Foo::getBar,
        Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

Comment: `f -> f.getBar().getName1()` requires me to cast `((Foo)f).getBar()...` to work, even though the list is definitly typed. I guess there is no way around it? I also just realized a little mistake in my question. Please have a look at the updated version

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Related to casting, the minimal code `@Getter
    public class Foo {
        private Bar bar;
        private boolean set;
    }

    @Getter
    public class Bar {
        private String name1;
        private String name2;
    }

    public void sorting(List<Foo> fooList) {
        fooList.sort(Comparator.comparing(f -> f.getBar().getName1(),
                Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
    }` doesn't require it. See the update for the edit.

Comment: Ugh, now I see my mistake... I was using the wrong interface on `Bar`... Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

For `Comparator<T>`, the signature is:

```
static <T,U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T>
  comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

So the result of `Foo::getBar` must implement `Comparable`. `Bar` implements `Comparator`, not `Comparable`.

Oracle's documentation on the [comparing​](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) method is elaborated with (emphasis mine):

> Accepts a function that extracts a **Comparable** sort key from a type T..